# Removing simultaneous selection in two listboxs (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose we have two listboxs (lstbox1 & lstbox2) within a userform in VBA Excel.

How can I remove selections from lstbox1 if an item from lstbox2 gets selected and vice versa ?

Here goes my attempt, however I have the impression my code only gets triggered if I click a button after selecting items ... My goal is to remove selection automatically when we hover and choose an item:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    For i = listbox1.ListCount - 1 to 0 Step -1
          If Listbox1.Selected(i) = True then 
                 ListBox2.ListIndex = -1  'Is this line correct to remove selection ?
          End if
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_Change()
    For i = listbox2.ListCount - 1 to 0 Step -1
          If Listbox2.Selected(i) = True then 
                 ListBox1.ListIndex = -1
          End if
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Edit:** I achieve the wanted result using this instead

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
        For i = listbox2.ListCount - 1 to 0 Step -1
              If Listbox2.Selected(i) = True then 
                     ListBox2.Selected(i) = False 
              End if
        Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_Change()
        For i = listbox1.ListCount - 1 to 0 Step -1
              If Listbox1.Selected(i) = True then 
                     ListBox1.Selected(i) = False 
              End if
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Presumably you have enabled multiple selections in each of these list boxes? If it is only single select then 
`Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    ListBox2.ListIndex = -1
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox2_Change()
    ListBox1.ListIndex = -1
End Sub`
is all you need.
You also need `Option Explicit` at the top of your module - you did not declare `i`